# Sticky form rollback when i try to fill form

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-animate, focus, blur

I have placed a sticky form in right side of my website. It work perfectly when i rollover and rollout. but when i try to fill the form it roll back to side wall. some blur and focus script need to be placed and I am unable to figure it out. following is the image and code.

```
$('.sticky').hover(function(){
    $('.sticky').css('right', 0+'px')},
function(){
    $('.sticky').css('right', -320+'px');
});
```

my form id is sticky-form. Please advice or guide, all i want is to for stay there if any of its field is blur/focus and if not then it can roll back to the wall.
thanks

Comment: i think its because you are using *hover* rather than mouseover and mouseout where you have more control. So, in hover, before you are out, when you *try* to hit on it, its already a new hover.

Comment: 'code'
$('.sticky').on('mouseout', function(){
  if ( $('input:focus').length > 0 && $('textarea:focus').length > 0 && $('select:focus').length > 0) {
   $('.sticky').css('right', 0+'px'); 
  }else{
   $('.sticky').css('right', -320+'px');
  }
 });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $('.sticky').on('mouseout', function(){
    if ( $('input:focus').length > 0 || $('textarea:focus').length > 0 || $('select:focus').length > 0) {
        $('.sticky').css('right', 0+'px');  
    }else{
        $('.sticky').css('right', -320+'px');
    }
});
```

this some how worked but still need some options. in this condition i need to click on page to release my focus to blur even few fields of my form is fill. in initial it work like in and out. when i click on any field and mouseout, sticky remains there. thanks cylua2...